# Nginx + uwsgi + django + odbc - issues with not finding odbc driver, possibly related to wrong user somewhere

Tags: python, django, nginx, teradata, uwsgi

I'm trying to connect to teradata through odbc from django under CentOS. The problem is that odbc cannot find teradata driver when run under django. If I run the script from python directly (or through django's `./manage command`) it works fine, which makes me to believe that something in the chain above is being run under wrong (possibly "nginx") user, as I assume teradata (odbc?) is unable to locate `.odbc.ini` in the home directory of the current user.

I had similar problem under Debian and solved it by changing uwsgi user to match, though CentOS uwsgi config is slightly different and the same change doesn't help.

The error I'm getting:

```
ERROR - ('DRIVER_NOT_FOUND', "No driver found for 'Teradata'.  Available drivers: PostgreSQL,MySQL")
```

`.odbc.ini` with teradata config is located under /home/myuser/.odbc.ini

> /etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown myuser:myuser /run/uwsgi'
ExecStart=/usr/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites --logto /home/myuser/log.log
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

> uwsgi app.ini config

```
[uwsgi]
chmod-socket = 664
chown-socket = nginx #cannot change this to myuser, getting 502
uid = myuser #this is what fixed it on Debian
gid = myuser #this is what fixed it on Debian
vhost = true
plugins = python
socket = /home/myuser/app.sock
master = true
enable-threads = true
processes = 2
module = app.wsgi
wsgi-file = /home/myuser/wsgi.py
chdir = /home/myuser/app/
post-buffering = 1
buffer-size = 32768
vacuum = false
```

> nginx config

```
upstream django {
    server unix:/home/myuser/app.sock;
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name myapp.com;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/myuser/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

> teradata connection log (seeing correct user here too)

```
/********************************************************************************
 * Application Name: myapp
 *          Version: 1.0
 *       Run Number: xxx
 *             Host: pushnotif01
 *         Platform: Linux-centos
 *          OS User: myuser
 *   Python Version: 2.7.5
 *  Python Compiler: GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
 *     Python Build: ('default', 'Sep 15 2016 22:37:39')
 *  UdaExec Version: 15.10.0.18
 *     Program Name: uwsgi
 *      Working Dir: /home/myuser
 *          Log Dir: /home/myuser/logs
 *         Log File: /home/myuser/logs/app.log
 *     Config Files: [u'/etc/udaexec.ini: Not Found', u'/home/myuser/udaexec.ini: Not Found', u'/home/myuser/app/udaexec.ini: Not Found']
 *      Query Bands: ApplicationName=myapp;Version=1.0;JobID=20161006121335-43;ClientUser=myuser;Production=False;udaAppLogFile=/home/myuser/logs/app.log;UtilityName=PyTd;UtilityVersion=15.10.0.18
********************************************************************************
```

> App launch script:

```
sudo service nginx restart
sudo service uwsgi restart
```

If I try to create a test file from within the same code it is being created under correct `myuser` user, so it seems that django is running under the right user, yet odbc is still unable to find its config for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error this made it work for now:

1. Add `HOME` env variable to uwsgi's app.ini config pointing to home dir of the right user:

   ```
   env=HOME=/home/myuser
   ```
2. Pass `odbcLibPath` param explicitly when initializing the teradata connection:

   ```
   udaExec = teradata.UdaExec(odbcLibPath='/opt/teradata/client/15.00/odbc_64/lib/libodbc.so', ...)
   ```